# Convert String to Integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, integer

I have a string value of 41,123 and I want to convert it to an integer in JavaScript.

I tried parseInt(41,123, 10) and parseFloat, but nothing gives me correct answer.

ParseInt, parseFloat work well until comma is encountered, but to above the result is '41'.

Does anyone have an idea about the fix?

Comment: parseInt("41,123", 10) = 41, what's wrong with this result?

Comment: Yes, but I think it should be 41123. The comma is a notation for thousands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myInt = parseInt("41,123,10".replace(/,/g,""));
```

Comment: You are not reading the question right. It is 43,123 radix 10 - the solution is still a regex since it could be 1,000,000 - put the number in a var instead

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
Number(s.replace(/,/g, ""))
```

**Regex is needed in replacement to remove all comma characters, otherwise only one comma will be replaced.**

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the comma, and then parse; let's say the number is variable `s`:

```
parseInt(s.replace(/,/g, '')
```